# Launch zed editor from command line opening specified directory

Tags: editor

I've tried launched zed per the following:

`open -a /Applications/Zed.app -n --args "$PWD"`

However `zed` does not respect the passed $PWD and only loads the prior open folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
alias zed="open -a /Applications/Zed.app -n"
```

and then

`zed .` works for me.

Comment: Switched this to:
`alias zed="/Applications/Zed.app/Contents/MacOS/cli"`
Then I was able to open with `zed .`

Answer (score 3):

For some reason (I'm guessing because of the way Zed manages networking for collaborative editing) it is *not* possible to launch multiple instances of Zed using the `-n` option of the `open` command (at least not in the current `0.120.5` version).

Instead, it turns out that there is a `cli` interface to Zed which I which I discovered accidentally by poking around the `.app` container.

The cli utility has help though, which gives you this:

```
% /Applications/Zed.app/Contents/MacOS/cli --help
zed

USAGE:
    cli [OPTIONS] [PATHS_WITH_POSITION]...

ARGS:
    <PATHS_WITH_POSITION>...
            A sequence of space-separated paths that you want to open.

            Use `path:line:row` syntax to open a file at a specific location. Non-existing paths and
            directories will ignore `:line:row` suffix.

OPTIONS:
    -b, --bundle-path <BUNDLE_PATH>
            Custom Zed.app path

    -h, --help
            Print help information

    -v, --version
            Print Zed's version and the app path

    -w, --wait
            Wait for all of the given paths to be opened/closed before exiting
%
```

So (it turns out) you can start Zed with `/Applications/Zed.app/Contents/MacOS/cli {directory}`, and if you run *that* command a *second* time with a *different* `{directory}` then it will open up a "new instance" (which is really a new window owned by the *same* instance).